# Oracle connection error 'Keyword not supported: 'incr pool size'.'

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a working project with the same Oracle connection. I created a new form to get another table. When I use the same connection string, it gives me the error that appears in the question title. I have read that `incr pool size` is used only in Oracle and not supported in SQL. Why am I getting this error?
My connection string looks like...

```
string OracleConnection(){
 return "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSERVICE)));User Id = ADMIN; Password = ADMIN; Pooling=true; Min Pool Size=1; Connection Lifetime=180; Max Pool Size=50; Incr Pool Size=5";
}
```

I use it to get data as follows:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
OracleCommand cmd;
string qry = " select IS_EDITABLE from EDITABLE_CONTROLS where CONTROL_NAME=:Control_Name";
con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.OracleConnection();
con.Open();
cmd = new OracleCommand(qry, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("Control_Name", ECN);
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    if (dr[0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        resp = true;
    }
    else
    {
        resp = false;
    }
}
```

The above error occurs on this line of my code:

```
con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.OracleConnection();
```

Kindly don't mark it duplicate just for its name.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the deprecated System.Data.OracleClient API? That one does not support the Incr Pool Size parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: how can i upgrade it?

Comment: I can't understand this then, as I have been using the same connection string in this project for more than 99+ times.

Comment: I finally sorted out my wrong version of OracleClient. Finally resolved this by using `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;`. Thank you @ultddave for guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my code that was using of wrong version of `OracleClient`.
This error is now resolved using related `OracleCLient` version which is for my OracleCLient as:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
```

before this the wrong version which I was using was :

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
```

I am writing this answer and marking it solution so that it may help anyone who face same situation.

Happy coding.